# marker cluster locations from database

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

i have been useing a map with markers from sql db and would like to add marker clusters as i get more markers.

on it self the code for the map and the code for the marker cluster from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering#maps_marker_clustering-javascript  works fine,
i have tried to combain them and keep geting a map with no markers .

this is the cluster map from google which works fine

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Marker Clustering</title>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@google/markerclustererplus@4.0.1/dist/markerclustererplus.min.js"></script>
    <script
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCRLmpZiLZ9e-p6wRbwGWH6_1AS5M31vSI&callback=initMap&libraries=&v=weekly"
      defer
    ></script>
    <style type="text/css">
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }

      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html,
      body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
    <script>
      function initMap() {
        const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
          zoom: 2,
          center: { lat: -28.024, lng: 140.887 },
        });
        // Create an array of alphabetical characters used to label the markers.
        const labels = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        // Add some markers to the map.
        // Note: The code uses the JavaScript Array.prototype.map() method to
        // create an array of markers based on a given "locations" array.
        // The map() method here has nothing to do with the Google Maps API.
        const markers = locations.map((location, i) => {
          return new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location,
            label: labels[i % labels.length],
          });
        });
        // Add a marker clusterer to manage the markers.
        new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
          imagePath:
            "https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m",
        });
      }
      const locations = [
        { lat: -31.56391, lng: 147.154312 },
        { lat: -33.718234, lng: 150.363181 },
        { lat: -33.727111, lng: 150.371124 },
        { lat: -33.848588, lng: 151.209834 },
        { lat: -33.851702, lng: 151.216968 },
        { lat: -34.671264, lng: 150.863657 },
        { lat: -35.304724, lng: 148.662905 },
        { lat: -36.817685, lng: 175.699196 },
        { lat: -36.828611, lng: 175.790222 },
        { lat: -37.75, lng: 145.116667 },
        { lat: -37.759859, lng: 145.128708 },
        { lat: -37.765015, lng: 145.133858 },
        { lat: -37.770104, lng: 145.143299 },
        { lat: -37.7737, lng: 145.145187 },
        { lat: -37.774785, lng: 145.137978 },
        { lat: -37.819616, lng: 144.968119 },
        { lat: -38.330766, lng: 144.695692 },
        { lat: -39.927193, lng: 175.053218 },
        { lat: -41.330162, lng: 174.865694 },
        { lat: -42.734358, lng: 147.439506 },
        { lat: -42.734358, lng: 147.501315 },
        { lat: -42.735258, lng: 147.438 },
        { lat: -43.999792, lng: 170.463352 },
      ];
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

this is the map i use with db markers and works fine

```
  <?php
    include("classes/user-map.php");
?>


<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/user-map.css" type="text/css"/>
    </head>
<body>
 <!-- google API &key=  -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?language=en&key=AIzaSyCRLmpZiLZ9e-p6wRbwGWH6_1AS5M31vSI"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCRLmpZiLZ9e-p6wRbwGWH6_1AS5M31vSI&libraries=places"></script>

 <!--top bar-->
 <div>
      <?php include("header.php");?>

 </div>


    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
        /**
         * Create new map
         */
         
        var infowindow;
        var map;
        var red_icon =  'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png' ;
        
        var locations = <?php get_confirmed_locations() ?>;
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 7,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(31.87916, 35.32910),
            mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), myOptions);



        /**
         * Global marker object that holds all markers.
         * @type {Object.<string, google.maps.LatLng>}
         */
        var markers = {};

        /**
         * Concatenates given lat and lng with an underscore and returns it.
         * This id will be used as a key of marker to cache the marker in markers object.
         * @param {!number} lat Latitude.
         * @param {!number} lng Longitude.
         * @return {string} Concatenated marker id.
         */
        var getMarkerUniqueId= function(lat, lng) {
            return lat + '_' + lng;
        };

        /**
         * Creates an instance of google.maps.LatLng by given lat and lng values and returns it.
         * This function can be useful for getting new coordinates quickly.
         * @param {!number} lat Latitude.
         * @param {!number} lng Longitude.
         * @return {google.maps.LatLng} An instance of google.maps.LatLng object
         */
        var getLatLng = function(lat, lng) {
            return new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
        };


        /**
         * Binds right click event to given marker and invokes a callback function that will remove the marker from map.
         * @param {!google.maps.Marker} marker A google.maps.Marker instance that the handler will binded.
         */
        var bindMarkerEvents = function(marker) {
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "rightclick", function (point) {
                var markerId = getMarkerUniqueId(point.latLng.lat(), point.latLng.lng()); // get marker id by using clicked point's coordinate
                var marker = markers[markerId]; // find marker
                removeMarker(marker, markerId); // remove it
            });
        };

 
        /**
         * loop through (Mysql) dynamic locations to add markers to map.
         */
        var i ; var confirmed = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
                map: map,
                icon :   locations[i][4] === '1' ?  red_icon  : purple_icon,
                html: "<div id='window_loc'>\n" +
                "<form method='GET' action='question.php'>\n" +
                "<table class=\"map1\">\n" +
                "<tr>\n" +
                "<td><input type='hidden'  id='manual_description'/>"+locations[i][3]+"</td></tr>\n" +
                "<tr>\n" +
                "<td><textarea disabled  id='question' placeholder='Question'>"+locations[i][5]+"</textarea></td></tr>\n" +
                "<tr>\n" +
                "<td><input type='hidden' name='location_id' id='location_id' value="+locations[i][0]+" /></td></tr>\n" +
                "<td><input id='button1' name='play' type='submit' value='play'/> </td></tr>\n" +
                "</table>\n" +
                "</form>\n" +
                "</div>"
            });


            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                return function() {
                    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                    confirmed =  locations[i][4] === '1' ?  'checked'  :  0;
                    $("#confirmed").prop(confirmed,locations[i][4]);
                    $("#location_id").val(locations[i][0]);
                    $("#description").val(locations[i][3]);
                    $("#form").show();
                    infowindow.setContent(marker.html);
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                }
            })(marker, i));
        }
         function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
            var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
                new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
                new XMLHttpRequest;

            request.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (request.readyState == 4) {
                    callback(request.responseText, request.status);
                }
            };

            request.open('GET', url, true);
            request.send(null);
        }
    </script>
```

this is what i have tried - imalementing the db markers in the cluster map with no sucsses

```
<?php
    include("classes/user-map.php");
?>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Marker Clustering</title>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@google/markerclustererplus@4.0.1/dist/markerclustererplus.min.js"></script>
    <script
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCRLmpZiLZ9e-p6wRbwGWH6_1AS5M31vSI&callback=initMap&libraries=&v=weekly"
      defer
    ></script>
    <style type="text/css">
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }

      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html,
      body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
    <script>
    
      function initMap() {
        const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
          zoom: 3,
          center: { lat: -28.024, lng: 140.887 },
        });
        // Create an array of alphabetical characters used to label the markers.
        const labels = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        var locations = <?php get_confirmed_locations() ?>;
        // Add some markers to the map.
        // Note: The code uses the JavaScript Array.prototype.map() method to
        // create an array of markers based on a given "locations" array.
        // The map() method here has nothing to do with the Google Maps API.
        const markers = locations.map((locations, i) => {
          return new google.maps.Marker({
            position: locations,
            label: labels[i % labels.length],
          });
        });
        // Add a marker clusterer to manage the markers.
        new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
          imagePath:
            "https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m",
        });
      }
      var markers = {};

        /**
        * Concatenates given lat and lng with an underscore and returns it.
        * This id will be used as a key of marker to cache the marker in markers object.
        * @param {!number} lat Latitude.
        * @param {!number} lng Longitude.
        * @return {string} Concatenated marker id.
        */
        var getMarkerUniqueId= function(lat, lng) {
            return lat + '_' + lng;
        };

        /**
        * Creates an instance of google.maps.LatLng by given lat and lng values and returns it.
        * This function can be useful for getting new coordinates quickly.
        * @param {!number} lat Latitude.
        * @param {!number} lng Longitude.
        * @return {google.maps.LatLng} An instance of google.maps.LatLng object
        */
        var getLatLng = function(lat, lng) {
            return new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
        };


        /**
        * Binds right click event to given marker and invokes a callback function that will remove the marker from map.
        * @param {!google.maps.Marker} marker A google.maps.Marker instance that the handler will binded.
        */
        var bindMarkerEvents = function(marker) {
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "rightclick", function (point) {
                var markerId = getMarkerUniqueId(point.latLng.lat(), point.latLng.lng()); // get marker id by using clicked point's coordinate
                var marker = markers[markerId]; // find marker
                removeMarker(marker, markerId); // remove it
            });
        };


        /**
        * loop through (Mysql) dynamic locations to add markers to map.
        */
        var i ; var confirmed = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
                map: map,
                icon :   locations[i][4] === '1' ?  red_icon  : purple_icon,
                html: "<div id='window_loc'>\n" +
                "<form method='GET' action='question.php'>\n" +
                "<table class=\"map1\">\n" +
                "<tr>\n" +
                "<td><input type='hidden'  id='manual_description'/>"+locations[i][3]+"</td></tr>\n" +
                "<tr>\n" +
                "<td><textarea disabled  id='question' placeholder='Question'>"+locations[i][5]+"</textarea></td></tr>\n" +
                "<tr>\n" +
                "<td><input type='hidden' name='location_id' id='location_id' value="+locations[i][0]+" /></td></tr>\n" +
                "<td><input id='button1' name='play' type='submit' value='play'/> </td></tr>\n" +
                "</table>\n" +
                "</form>\n" +
                "</div>"
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                return function() {
                    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                    confirmed =  locations[i][4] === '1' ?  'checked'  :  0;
                    $("#confirmed").prop(confirmed,locations[i][4]);
                    $("#location_id").val(locations[i][0]);
                    $("#description").val(locations[i][3]);
                    $("#form").show();
                    infowindow.setContent(marker.html);
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                }
            })(marker, i));
        }
        function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
            var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
                new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
                new XMLHttpRequest;

            request.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (request.readyState == 4) {
                    callback(request.responseText, request.status);
                }
            };

            request.open('GET', url, true);
            request.send(null);
        }
      var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers,
            {imagePath: `${path}/m`});
            
    </script>
    
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

this is the server php query for `locations`

```
<?php

function get_confirmed_locations(){

    $con=mysqli_connect ("localhost", 'root', '','');
    if (!$con) {
        die('Not connected : ' . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    // update location with location_status if admin location_status.
    $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT location_id ,lat,lng,description,location_status,question AS isconfirmed FROM `locations` WHERE  location_status = 1 ");

    $rows = array();

    while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        $rows[] = $r;

    }

    $indexed = array_map('array_values', $rows);
    $array = array_filter($indexed);
 

    echo json_encode($array);
    if (!$rows) {
        return null;
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest solution, push your markers into an array when you create them, create a `MarkerClusterer` using that array.

1. create an array to hold the markers (rather than an object), change:

   ```
    var markers = {};
   ```

to:

```
    var markers = [];
```

2. in the loop that creates your markers, push them onto that array:

   ```
    markers.push(marker);
   ```
3. after the loop is complete, create the `MarkerClusterer` using that array (the same code as in the example):

   ```
   // Add a marker clusterer to manage the markers.
   new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
     imagePath: "https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m",
   });
   ```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/sq5nuhgk/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
/**
 * Create new map
 */

var infowindow;
var map;
var red_icon = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png';

var locations = [
  ["name0", -31.56391, 147.154312],   ["name1", -33.718234, 150.363181],  ["name2", -33.727111, 150.371124],  ["name3", -33.848588, 151.209834],  ["name4", -33.851702, 151.216968],  ["name5", -34.671264, 150.863657],  ["name6", -35.304724, 148.662905],  ["name7", -36.817685, 175.699196],  ["name8", -36.828611, 175.790222],  ["name9", -37.75, 145.116667],  ["name10", -37.759859, 145.128708],  ["name11", -37.765015, 145.133858],  ["name12", -37.770104, 145.143299],  ["name13", -37.7737, 145.145187],  ["name14", -37.774785, 145.137978],  ["name15", -37.819616, 144.968119],  ["name16", -38.330766, 144.695692],  ["name17", -39.927193, 175.053218],  ["name18", -41.330162, 174.865694],  ["name19", -42.734358, 147.439506],  ["name20", -42.734358, 147.501315],  ["name21", -42.735258, 147.438],  ["name22", -43.999792, 170.463352]
]
var myOptions = {
  zoom: 7,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(31.87916, 35.32910),
  mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
};
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), myOptions);

/**
 * Global marker object that holds all markers.
 * @type {Object.<string, google.maps.LatLng>}
 */
var markers = [];
/**
 * Concatenates given lat and lng with an underscore and returns it.
 * This id will be used as a key of marker to cache the marker in markers object.
 * @param {!number} lat Latitude.
 * @param {!number} lng Longitude.
 * @return {string} Concatenated marker id.
 */
var getMarkerUniqueId = function(lat, lng) {
  return lat + '_' + lng;
};

/**
 * Creates an instance of google.maps.LatLng by given lat and lng values and returns it.
 * This function can be useful for getting new coordinates quickly.
 * @param {!number} lat Latitude.
 * @param {!number} lng Longitude.
 * @return {google.maps.LatLng} An instance of google.maps.LatLng object
 */
var getLatLng = function(lat, lng) {
  return new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
};


/**
 * Binds right click event to given marker and invokes a callback function that will remove the marker from map.
 * @param {!google.maps.Marker} marker A google.maps.Marker instance that the handler will binded.
 */
var bindMarkerEvents = function(marker) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "rightclick", function(point) {
    var markerId = getMarkerUniqueId(point.latLng.lat(), point.latLng.lng()); // get marker id by using clicked point's coordinate
    var marker = markers[markerId]; // find marker
    removeMarker(marker, markerId); // remove it
  });
};


/**
 * loop through (Mysql) dynamic locations to add markers to map.
 */
var i;
var confirmed = 0;
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map,
    // icon: locations[i][4] === '1' ? red_icon : purple_icon,
    html: "<div id='window_loc'>\n" +
      "<form method='GET' action='question.php'>\n" +
      "<table class=\"map1\">\n" +
      "<tr>\n" +
      "<td><input type='hidden'  id='manual_description'/>" + locations[i][3] + "</td></tr>\n" +
      "<tr>\n" +
      "<td><textarea disabled  id='question' placeholder='Question'>" + locations[i][5] + "</textarea></td></tr>\n" +
      "<tr>\n" +
      "<td><input type='hidden' name='location_id' id='location_id' value=" + locations[i][0] + " /></td></tr>\n" +
      "<td><input id='button1' name='play' type='submit' value='play'/> </td></tr>\n" +
      "</table>\n" +
      "</form>\n" +
      "</div>"
  });
  bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
      confirmed = locations[i][4] === '1' ? 'checked' : 0;
      $("#confirmed").prop(confirmed, locations[i][4]);
      $("#location_id").val(locations[i][0]);
      $("#description").val(locations[i][3]);
      $("#form").show();
      infowindow.setContent(marker.html);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));
  markers.push(marker);
}
map.fitBounds(bounds);
// Add a marker clusterer to manage the markers.
new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
  imagePath: "https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m",
});

function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
  var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
    new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
    new XMLHttpRequest;

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      callback(request.responseText, request.status);
    }
  };

  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.send(null);
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Marker Clustering</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@google/markerclustererplus@4.0.1/dist/markerclustererplus.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&libraries=&v=weekly"></script>
  <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: i have changed your code `var locations = <?php get_confirmed_locations() ?>;` and it works ! thank you !

Comment: FYI - that was what would have been helpful in your original question (an example of the data in that array), figured it out from your "working" example, but things would have gone faster with that example.